# retornar variável de função python django

Tags: python, funções, django, django-templates

Tenho uma função que retorna vários valores, e queria passar dois deles pra fora da função, mas quando tento ele retorna que a variável fora da função não foi declarada.

Para exemplificar no código abaixo, gostaria que as listas teste3 e teste4 da função gerar_gráfico, fossem usadas na função index fora da função gerar_graficos, lembrando que é uma views do django.

Código da função:

```
class StorageData:
    list_shared = [] #lista compartilhada
    def __init__(self, *dados):
         self.list_shared.extend(dados) #inclui dados na lista

    def extend(self, *args):
         self.list_shared.extend(args)

    def reset(self):
        self.list_shared = [] #reseta lista caso queira zerar ela


def gerar_graficos(request):
    descricao = '01/02/2019 08:00'
    descricao2 = '01/02/2019 09:00'

    if request.method=='POST':
        descricao = request.POST['descricao']
        descricao2 = request.POST['descricao2']
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('banco')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(consulta do banco)
    teste = []
    teste2 = []
    teste3 = []
    teste4 = []


    d = 0
    for line in cur:
        teste.extend(line)
    for indice, c in enumerate(teste):
        #if c + 0 == c:
            teste3.extend([c - 10000])
        #else:
            d = 0


    cur.execute(consulta do banco)
    for coluna in cur:
        teste2.extend(coluna)
    for indice2, c in enumerate(teste2):
        if indice2 >= d:
            teste4.extend([c])

    transfer = StorageData()
    transfer.reset()
    transfer.extend(teste3,teste4)

    width_n = 0.001
    bar_color = 'yellow'

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    context = { 'descricao': descricao, 'descricao2': descricao2 }
    return render(request, 'core/graficos_list.html', context)
```

Código fora da função:

```
def index(request):
   trans = StorageData()
   my_list = trans.list_shared[0]
   my_list2 = trans.list_shared[1]
   fig = Figure()
   ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
   ax.plot(my_list, my_list2)
   #ax.bar(x_axis, y_axis, width=width_n, color=bar_color, align='center')
   ax.grid()
   buf = io.BytesIO()
   canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
   canvas.print_png(buf)
   response=HttpResponse(buf.getvalue(), content_type='image/png')
   return (response)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível acessar desta forma pois `descricao` e `descricao2` são variáveis validas apenas para o escopo da função `gerar_graficos()`.

Uma solução seria chamar essas funções `calcular_medida()` e `calcular_data()` dentro da `gerar_graficos()` isso se o `x_axis` e o `y_axis` forem utilizados no template.

```
def gerar_graficos(request):
    descricao = '01/02/2019 08:00'
    descricao2 = '01/02/2019 09:00'

    if request.method=='POST':
        descricao = request.POST['descricao']
        descricao2 = request.POST['descricao2']


    y_axis = calcular_medida(descricao,descricao2)
    x_axis = calcular_data(descricao, descricao2)
    context = { 'descricao': descricao, 'descricao2': descricao2, 'x_axis' : x_axis, 'y_axis': y_axis }
    return render(request, 'core/graficos_list.html', context)
```

Outro método seria chamar uma função em `gerar_gráficos()` que execute o que quer fazer.

```
def gerar_graficos(request):
    descricao = '01/02/2019 08:00'
    descricao2 = '01/02/2019 09:00'

    if request.method=='POST':
        descricao = request.POST['descricao']
        descricao2 = request.POST['descricao2']


    calculaXY(descricao,descricao2)
    context = { 'descricao': descricao, 'descricao2': descricao2 }
    return render(request, 'core/graficos_list.html', context)

def calculaXY(descricao,descricao2):
    y_axis =  []
    x_axis = []
    y_axis = calcular_medida(gerar_graficos.descricao,gerar_graficos.descricao2)
    x_axis = calcular_data(gerar_graficos.descricao, gerar_graficos.descricao2)
```

Recomendo dar uma lida sobre [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/) que pode facilitar toda essa questão de atributos e funções.

Comment: as duas soluções dão certo para a minha pergunta, então vou aceitar sua resposta, mas oq eu preciso não ta na pergunta, ai infelizmente não da certo, obrigado pela ajuda, e caso consiga ajudar mais, eu preciso fazer com que duas listas sejam lidas por duas views diferentes

Comment: @Guilherme Use a View sendo uma [classe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/), você pode ter um atributo de classe que seriam as duas listas, e pode usá-las de maneira independente nas duas funções.

Comment: Ai posso ter duas funções na classe que geram dois templates diferentes?

Comment: @Guilherme assim você consegue que as duas listas sejam atributos da classe e compartilhadas entre as duas funções, mas se o gráfico ter alguma relação com os dados o que você pode fazer é usar um front-end para gerar os graficos, colocando essas funções que calculam a medida no javascript do template, assim fica mais fácil dependendo da aplicação.

Comment: o gráfico é gerado a partir dos dados das listas, mas vou tentar fazer uma classe com as duas funções, sendo lidas cada uma por uma template, se nao der certo, vou pra sua dica do front end, valeu irmão

Answer (score 2):

@Guilherme,
Cara pelo que li nos comentários, você precisa fazer com que duas views diferentes acessem os mesmos dados.
Você pode tentar armazenar elas na session, como:

```py
 request.session['descricoes'] = [descrição, descricao2]
```

Porém esta forma não tenho certeza 100% que vai funcionar, mais não custa tentar.
Agora você pode criar uma classe para fazer essa operação de armazenar dados compartilhados.

```py
class StorageData:
    list_shared = [] #lista compartilhada
    def __init__(self, *dados):
         self.list_shared.extend(dados) #inclui dados na lista

    def reset(self):
        self.list_shared = [] #reseta lista caso queira zerar ela
```

Pronto agora para usar ela, basta instanciar a class é passar suas listas para dentro do construtor dela

```py
StorageData (descrição, descricao2)
```

E quando você quiser usar esses dados em outra view basta instanciar a classe novamente sem parâmetros e acessar a propriedade list_shared.

```py
#outra view para acessar os dados da descricao e descricao2
def sua_view(request):
    storage = StorageData()
    my_list = storage.list_shared # Aqui a propriedade irá retornar os mesmos dados que foi executado por outra instância passando os dados pelo construtor.
```

Tente fazer essas maneiras e se não funcionar poste aí pra ver se tem outras formas também.

Usando:
Aqui são duas views distintas que vão utilizar a classe

```py
def transfer(request):

    transfer = Storage()
    transfer.reset() # Coloquei apenas para resetar a lista para cadastrar novamente os mesmos dados, para não ficar adicionando um monte de vez a cada requisição

    descricao = ["Esta lista é a decricao"]
    descricao2 = ["Esta lista é a decricao2"]
    transfer.extend(descricao,descricao2) # Aqui adiciona os dados na classe

    return render(request,'core/transfer.html',context{'descricao':descricao,'descricao2':descricao2})

def Transfer_get(request):
    trans = Storage()
    descricao = trans.list_shared[0]  # Aqui recupera os valores adicionados na classe
    descricao2 = trans.list_shared[1]

    return render(request, 'core/transfer2.html', context={'descricao':descricao,'descricao2':descricao2})
```

No template apenas mostrei os dados

```py
{{ descricao }}
{{ descricao2 }}
```

Caso você prefira pode passar a lista completa para os templates e la fazer a interação na lista e exibir os dados dela.

```py
def Transfer_get(request):
    trans = Storage()
    lista = trans.list_shared  # Aqui recupera os valores adicionados na classe

    return render(request, 'core/transfer2.html', context={'lista':lista})
```

E no template interar essa lista.

Tambem criei as rotas para essas views. Fiz uma mudança simples na classe adicionando o método extend().

```py
class Storage:

    list_shared = []

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.list_shared.extend(args)

    def extend(self, *args):
        self.list_shared.extend(args)

    def reset(self):
        self.list_shared.clear()
```

Bom testei aqui é os valores passam normalmente para as duas views, e se eu adicionar mais algum valor na **list_shared** quando for consultar a lista os novos valores aparecem também sem problema.
Caso você tenha feito certinho e ver que não tem erro nenhum e mesmo assim não funciona, poste o código aqui do jeito que ficou para ver se podemos fazer alguma mudança ou algo do tipo.

Comment: editei o código da pergunta e fiz as alterações que voce me passou, não apresenta mais nenhum erro, mas gera um grafico sem dados nenhum, nao sei o pq, se puder ajudar, mas sua solução ta me dando uma luz no fim do túnel

Comment: editei a resposta da uma olhada la e vê se o sua implementação ficou parecida com essa.

Comment: implementação ta identica, mas agora ele apresenta o seguinte erro: "list index out of range" e esse erro:  "my_list = trans.list_shared[0] "

Comment: Posta ai o seu código das views onde você esta criando a lista e acessando ela, e também a classe transfer. Porque vai fica difícil desobrir onde esta o erro. Este erro gerado é porque você esta tentando acessar um indíce de uma lista que não existe.

Comment: editei a pergunta ai com o código atualizado

Comment: fiz varios testes, inclusive com duas listas que criei com valores de 0 a 5, e sempre da o mesmo erro

Comment: Bom cara me parece estar tudo certo e não era para aparecer esse erro de acesso a lista na posição 0. Tente depurar o código para ver o que esta sendo passado para a list_shared, assim você consegue ver melhor os possíveis erros.

Comment: agora só segunda, codigo ficou no pc da empresa, vou tentar e te retorno

Comment: Beleza segunda agente tenta achar esse erro. Falou bom FDS

Comment: Valeu irmao, então nada no debug retorna sem erros

Comment: Na sua view, quando vc debuga a list_shared fica preenchida? Porque se a list_shared não estiver sendo preenchida na view vai dá erro de acesso mesmo, tenta ver se o que você está passando pra list_shared está do jeito que você imagina mesmo. Pq agora fica mais difícil ajudar descobrir o erro. O mais provável está na hora de vc preencher a lista na view. Dá uma olhada e faça um debug detalhado e estiver conforme o esperado.

Comment: Retorna a list_shared como vazia, preciso ver o pq

Comment: tem alguma luz ai?

Comment: Eae Guilherme, então cara, fica difícil saber o porquê não está preenchendo sua lista, provavelmente alguma coisa na logíca da sua viu. E fica difícil saber sem debugar o código. O que poso tentar é pegar sei código e fazer um teste aqui, mais preciso de um modelo de resultados que a sua consulta retorna, e qual o resultado final esperado para mandar para as outras views.